# Intel and Gnu Fortran compile errors

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have the following code where I need to use compiler specific way to initialize the `elements` array. How to get a common compilable source for both compilers?

```
TYPE, PUBLIC :: RotationMatrixClass
  PRIVATE
#ifdef isGnu
  ! this crashes the Intel compiler
  REAL, DIMENSION(3,3) :: elements = reshape( (/1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 /), (/ 3,3/))
#else
  ! this does not compile on gfortran
  REAL,DIMENSION(3,3) :: elements = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
#endif


END TYPE
```

Comment: What kind of errors you get then? The other method is quite strange. Which compiler versions? Which flags?

Comment: Especially we need more details about your Intel compiler problems.

Comment: Indeed, it is a rank  array. Perhaps Intel has some extension allowing this assignment. I am wondering what kind of problems might Intel have with the first one, because it is  Fortran  90 and a common type of code too. Perhaps some specifics with the default component initialization, but we really need more from Menno, People asking questions should really wait at least a few minutes for comments, I was commenting 2 minutes after the question was asked...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I basically set the following 
```module test

IMPLICIT NONE
PRIVATE

TYPE, PUBLIC :: RotationMatrixClass
  PRIVATE
#ifdef isGnu
  ! this crashes the Intel compiler
  REAL, DIMENSION(3,3) :: elements = reshape( (/1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 /), (/ 3,3/))
#else
  ! this does not compile on gfortran
  REAL,DIMENSION(3,3) :: elements = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],[0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
#endif


END TYPE

END MODULE```

Comment: With gfortran I get `Error: Incompatible ranks 2 and 1 in assignment at (1)` , which makes sense seeing your comments on rank. I'm afraid I cant' reproduce the Intel compiler crash, sorry... I got a message like "internal compiler problem, contact Intel support"

Comment: *I got a message like "internal compiler problem, contact Intel support"*.  Aberrant code shouldn't cause that message, that's an internal compiler problem and you should contact Intel support.  Did you ?  Sure, it's possible your code is so wonky the compiler has a nervous breakdown (or the equivalent in code) but a well-behaving compiler should issue an error message without crashing.  And if you had reported that accurately in your original question @VladimirF and I wouldn't have wasted any time trying to figure out what was wrong with your code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thank you for you frank comments, I will take them to heart for the next time I run into a problem. I totally agree I could have written it up more clearly.